# FreeBSD 8 Kernel Configuration Error Using the VESA Option

Tags: configuration, freebsd, kernel

I'm trying to reconfigure FreeBSD 8 (amd64) to allow for a high resolution terminal by following [these](http://www.freebsdwiki.net/index.php/High_Resolution_Console) instructions.  The problem is that when I add the two lines:

```
options VESA
options SC_PIXEL_MODE
```

and try to build:

```
make buildkernel KERNCONF=VESAKERN
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/src/sys/amd64/conf/VESAKERN: unknown option "VESA"
```

and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VESA doesn't work on FreeBSD/amd64, VESA bios functions are 32bit i386 code. 
FreeBSD/amd64 cannot make calls to these functions.